# How to create custom template dropdownlist kendo with MVVM?

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, kendo-ui

How to create dropdownlist kendo with MVVM?
this is the example of custom dropdonwlist, but without MVVM
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/template
How i create this with MVVM(so with data-bind)?

Comment: You mean something like this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/mvvm ?

Comment: yes, but with the previous example custom template

Comment: You provided a wrong link, can you edit the question with the correct one?

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: I need to create a custom template for dropdownlist but i'm working with MVVM. I think it should be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the configuration options you see with jquery syntax (as per most of the examples you see) are also available with declarative syntax (which you use for MVVM). So where the example in the link you provide has this:

```
footerTemplate: 'Total #: instance.dataSource.total() # items found'
```

You would use:

```
data-footer-template = 'Total #: instance.dataSource.total() # items found'
```

Generally speaking, the camel case you use for jquery syntax becomes 'data-' followed by all lower case with hyphens between each word.